# What am I doing wrong … ly?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I frequently hear:

> What am I doing wrong?

But shouldn't it be

> What am I doing wrongly?

instead?  A quick ngram search reveals the latter is never used.  Why is there no *-ly*?  Isn't the former wrong?

Comment: @Ustanak: Wrong. _Wrong_ is an adverb as well as an adjective. _Wrongly_ is only an adverb.

Comment: @ColinFine I'd cleared this with another user before you told me this. I forgot to delete my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[wrong](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrong?s=t)" and "[wrongly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wrongly)" are both common and legitimate adverbs in modern English. The former is much more common. (COCA tells me ["wrong" as an adverb](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=45466369) is 6.28 times more common than ["wrongly"](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=45466380)) Of course, it's not that precise, but it relies on a pretty good approximation.

> ### Wrong
>
> *adverb*
>     11. in a wrong manner; not rightly; awry; amiss

Comment: "Wrongly" is almost never used except in phrases borrowed from legalese. Look at the context of the examples in those links. "Wrongly accused," "wrongly convicted," and so on.